# How to iterate through directories in Python using Pathlib

Tags: python, directory, glob, subdirectory, pathlib

I'm working with Python 3 and I need to perform some operations on folders, using Pathlib and checking if they are folders.

The operation I'm gonna do is something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
source_path = Path("path_directory_string")

for a in source_path.iterdir():
    if a.is_dir():
        for b in a.iterdir():
            if b.is_dir():
                for c in b.iterdir():
                    if c.is_dir():
                        # do something
```

My question is if there is a better way to do this. Looking through the past asked questions, it looks like the best way to do this is using the method glob of Pahtlib. So, since I have three levels of depth, I tried this:

```
for a in source_path.glob("**/**/**"):
    if a.is_dir():
        print(a)
```

and it almost works. The issue is that this returns not just the deepest-level folders, but also their parents. Did I make some mistakes formatting the glob pattern? Or does it exist a better way to list just the deepest_level elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for a in source_path.glob("*/*/*"):
    if a.is_dir():
        print(a)
```

From the documentation: The `**` pattern means “this directory and all subdirectories, recursively”, whereas one `*` is a text wildcard.